# How do I correctly format this jsonnet array output?

Tags: jsonnet

I have the following JSON and am using the -y option to produce a yaml output.

```
{
  array: [
    {item1: 1},
    {item2: 2},    
  ]   
}
```

I would like to produce (desired)

```
{
   "array": 
      -  "item1": 1,
      -  "item2": 2
}
```

but I am getting

```
{
   "array": [
      {
         "item1": 1
      },
      {
         "item2": 2
      }
   ],
}
```

Note the curly brackets in the actual output.  Is it possible to use jsonnet to produce the desired yaml output?

Comment: Your desired output isn't JSON. Are you certain that's what you're trying to produce?

Comment: @larsks Correct, my desired output is YAML. I am using the -y option. Added to the question above

Comment: Note that your desired output isn't valid YAML, either. You would need to drop the `[` and `]`. That said, it's a weird combination of formatting -- using one syntax for the outer dictionary, but another for the inner dictionary. I wonder if any tool could produce exactly that? I'm not sure.

Comment: @larsks Apologies, you are right about the square brackets - I have been through so many iterations I am getting crosseyed.  So I take from your response that this is not a normal use of jsonnet.  Is there a way to customize the output or write more complex transformations?

Comment: I take back what I said earlier -- even with the fix I suggested, that's still not valid YAML. I've left an answer with one suggestion for getting a more canonical YAML format, but if you're looking for a jsonnet-only solution we'll need to wait for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to go from this (which is both valid JSON and valid
YAML):

```
{
   "array": [
      {
         "item1": 1
      },
      {
         "item2": 2
      }
   ],
}
```

To this:

```
array:
  - item1: 1
  - item2: 2
```

You could just pipe the result through [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```
$ cat input.jsonnet
{
  array: [
    {item1: 1},
    {item2: 2},    
  ]   
}
$ jsonnet input.jsonnet | yq -y
array:
  - item1: 1
  - item2: 2
```

If you *really* want the final output to look like this:

```
{
  "array":
    - item1: 1
    - item2: 2
}
```

Note that is neither valid JSON nor valid YAML (try pasting that into a YAML validator, for example). You would need to
write some sort of custom output format to get that output (perhaps the docs in the "[Custom Output Formats](https://jsonnet.org/articles/output-formats.html)" section would be helpful on this front, although I haven't tried any of that myself).